# JOptionPane not showing when invalid date is detected

Tags: java, date, validation, exception, joptionpane

I am trying to check if a String in the format of `MM/dd/yyyy`  is a valid date that exists. For example, February 31, 2000 does not exist so I expect that my program will show a JOptionPane that states it is an invalid date. Whenever I enter invalid dates like this, I get the exception

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31'

It is able to detect that it is an invalid date however the **JOptionPane is not displaying when I try to click the button to save the record**.

Here is my source code: *(I included my `isFuture()`  method in case it affects my case)*

**Record.java**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    Object source = e.getSource();
    
    int monthInt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < month.length; i++) 
    {
        if (month[i].equals((String)cbMonth.getSelectedItem())) 
        {
            monthInt = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    int dayInt = (int)cbDay.getSelectedItem();
    int yearInt = (int)cbYear.getSelectedItem();
    
    LocalDate bDay = LocalDate.of(yearInt, monthInt, dayInt);
    String dateStr = Integer.toString(monthInt) + "/" + Integer.toString(dayInt) + "/" + Integer.toString(yearInt);
    
    if (source == button)
    {
        // other if statements
        
        // else if given date is in the future
        else if (Person.isFuture(bDay) == true)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fInfo, "An IllegalArgumentException Caught: Date given is in the future!", "Error Screen", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        
        // else if invalid date
        else if (Person.isValid(dateStr) == false)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fInfo, "An IllegalArgumentException Caught: Invalid date!", "Error Screen", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        
        // else add record to map
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
// isFuture
public static boolean isFuture(LocalDate date) 
{
    LocalDate curDate = LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 1);
    return curDate.isBefore(date);
}

// isValid()
public static boolean isValid(String date) 
{
    boolean valid = false;

    try {
        LocalDate.parse(date,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu")
                        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
        );
        valid = true;

    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: The exception is thrown from your call `LocalDate.of(yearInt, monthInt, dayInt);`. Because of the exception you never come down to your `if` statement trying to check the validity and show a message. Instead you need to wrap the mentioned call in `try`-`catch`, catch the exception and display the `JOptionPane` when you do.

Comment: @OleV.V. I see. I tried to remove it and the JOptionPane for the invalid date finally showed up. Thanks for your help!